# How to make knitr work with c.trellis?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, lattice, trellis

With `knitr` I try to product and combine two `lattice` plots with `c.trellis()`, but instead of the expected combined plot I get what looks like the internal representation of the combined trellis object:

[image]

MWE:

````
---
title: "Knitr and c.trellis"
author: "David Lindelöf"
date: "17 February 2016"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
foo <- xyplot(1 ~ 1)
bar <- xyplot(2 ~ 1)
c(foo, bar)
```
````

I have also tried calling `print(c(foo, bar))` in a separate chunk, without success. Am I doing something wrong, or is this an issue with `knitr`?

Comment: Ah got it. I had forgotten the call to `library(latticeExtra)` that defines the `trellis` method for `c()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to include a call to `library(latticeExtra)`, which defined the `c.trellis()` method.

Comment: You can [accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if it solved your problem. (EDIT: Just realized your 12k reputation; you probaby know that ...)